# AWS: get SQS url in SAM template.yml file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

How can I set up SQS url into the lambda Environment Variables?
For example we can get URN for DynamoDB streams: !GetAtt SuperTable.StreamArn .
I want to do something like that for SQS uri..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sqs-queue.html#aws-resource-sqs-queue-return-values)

```
!Ref YourQueueLogicalResourceName
```

returns the queue URL.

Comment: The URL provided is not available now. We can view [this reference from AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sqs-queue.html#aws-resource-sqs-queue-return-values)  instead.
It said: When you pass the logical ID of this resource to the intrinsic Ref function, Ref returns the queue URL. For example: `{ "Ref": "https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/123456789012/ab1-MyQueue-A2BCDEF3GHI4" }`

Comment: Thanks! I'll update the link in my answer